# C# reading information from Android

Tags: c#, android, json, web-services

i trying to do a simple login function.
The login will be made by an App and the information goes to a WebService (in C#).

My app is send the information to the server via HttpPost. But i can't get and return this information on the Web Service side

To make the request (android side) i was using:

```
// Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.getText().toString()));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass.getText().toString()));

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

On the WebService side, i was try to use the **Serialize** method, but it doens't work

Ps.: In order to test, i tried to run on another WebService (this one built with PHP), and works fine.

Any ideas how to make this work??

**[Edit]**

This is the web service side:

```
[HttpPost]
public string LogarAplicativo()
{
    //Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string jsonData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonData);

    //DB validation's

    var json = "";
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    json = serializer.Serialize(new { success = "0", message = "Test message!" });
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Show your web service code, and explain what "doesn't work" means.  Have you tried calling the web service from a browser?

Comment: Hey @nasch, i update the post with the Web service side. By doesnt work i mean that function 'LogarAplicativo' can't read the information passed by the httppost (on the App side)

Comment: I used fiddler to test on the browser and the json response was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send information with `UrlEncodedFormEntity`, it will look like a [the contents of an HTTP form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms):

```
param1=value1&param2=value2
```

This is not JSON data, so your serialization code doesn't work because it is a completely different structure. Parsing form data requires different methods like [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973737/parse-through-post).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the light Glorfindel, when i arrive at home i'll test this HttpUtility.ParseQueryString

Comment: the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString works perfectly, now i realize my mistake, thanks a lot again